# While loop with an exception after a count is reached

Tags: functions, loop

I'm trying to edit the tag.php page so that it displays all tagged posts (as it normally does) 'but' I want to call a function after the 3rd post in the loop.

Current Code

```
<?php /* The loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any suggestions on how to insert the following function after the **3rd** post in the loop?

```
<?php echo someFunction() ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the build in loop counter, `$current_post` which you can access in the main query with `$wp_query->current_post`. (*Just a note, the counter starts at `0`, so post `1` will be `0`*)

The main query uses [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), `$wp_query` being the query variable used, so have a look at the [Methods and Properties](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties) which you can make use of and the uses of these Methods and Properties

Inside your loop, just before `endwhile`, add the following

```
if( 2 === $wp_query->current_post ) {
    echo someFunction();
}
```

Comment: My pleasure Enjoy :-)